# Initializing a Subclassed UIViewController with a Required Coder Init - What to Do?

Tags: ios, swift

This is probably the silliest question to date - but I am having problems with initializing a subclassed view controller with a customized required coder initializer (specifically using the QRCoder pod; and to not expose code I don't own, I'll be using example classes in my case).

Here are the essentials.

```
class A: UIViewController {

    public var name = String()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        name = "This is a test"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Then we have...

```
class B: A {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        name = "What what"
    }
}
```

If I attempt to generate a new view controller of B in say, a button tap on C...

```
class C: UIViewController  {

    let button = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)}

    } 

    @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let viewOfB = B()
        present(viewOfB, animated: true)
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile = because my call of `let viewOfB = B()` is missing the `coder` parameter.

The problem is, if I add a `coder` parameter, what in the world do I put in there? I've tried filling it with just an empty(?) NSCoder, like so

```
let emptyCoder = NSCoder()
let viewOfB = B(coder: emptyCoder)
```

But then upon a run and button tap, I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -decodeObjectForKey: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class NSCoder: Create a concrete instance!'
```

I've tried adding a convenience initializer to A (where I have to run a `self.init` instead of `super.init` for some reason), but doing that gives me an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS_ERROR`.

What exactly do I need to provide to an `init:(coder)` instance to be able to... get things going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly do I need to provide to an `init:(coder)` instance to be able to... get things going?

Nothing. Stop thinking about `init(coder:)`.

Here's the actual problem. When you say `B()`, you are calling `init()`. But there is no `init()`, because where would it come from? You didn't implement any such method in A. And it is not inherited from the superclass (UIViewController), because you effectively destroyed all inherited initializers when you implemented `init(coder:)`.

So if you want to say `B()`, you must implement `init()` explicitly in A, yourself, like this:

```
class A: UIViewController {

    public var name = String()

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        name = "This is a test"
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you will still be left with the problem that this line is total nonsense: `button(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)}` But that's a separate issue.

Comment: Aha! Brilliant. Moving logic from the required init to just a plain init did indeed do the trick. 

Also, re: that line - yeah I missed the `addTarget` function, great catch!